# How to change item size based on screen width when using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

In my collection view using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, I would like the item size to be 85x85 when the view width is small, otherwise 100x100. But this is specified when creating the layout so how do you change the layout size when the screen width changes, for example rotating the iPhone or changing the split view configuration on iPad?

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = {
    let size = CGFloat(view.bounds.width < 375 ? 85 : 100)
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(size), heightDimension: .absolute(size))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(size))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section:)`, which is a *static* way of setting a section, use the other initializer, [`init(sectionProvider:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout/3199214-init), where you pass a *section provider function*. Your function now receives the environment as a parameter, including the collection view size, so now you can make your decision in real time depending on the environment. And you get called again if the environment changes, so presto, you can deal with the app changing size (as in an iPad that goes into split screen mode).

Comment: Yes, I do. :) Let me just finish editing my answer first.

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p466ComposableLayoutFunhouse/ComposableLayoutFunhouse/ViewController.swift - the first two sections illustrate the use of the environment size to dictate the layout details.